# Why won't a JavaFx project run when an FXML file is replaced

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I've got a JavaFx project that I built using Netbeans and JavaFx Scene Builder.

There are 3 files: the Main Class file, the FXML file and the controller.

Now, the problem is that I'm trying to copy and paste an earlier GUI JXML file from a previous project, but when I do so, the project won't run. Changing the URL to the controller doesn't help.

Everything works perfectly until I do the copy-paste.

**The files are:**

```
Sample.FXML             -> The orriginal GUI
SampleController.java   -> The Controller class

Home.FXML               -> The FXML file whose structure is to be copied to orriginal Sample.FXML
```

Here are the files:

**Sample.FXML** *(before the copy)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="wakiliproject.SampleController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**SampleController.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

**Home.FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="624.0" prefWidth="900.0" styleClass="AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="wakiliproject.SampleController">
  <children>
    <Pane id="wrapperPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="700.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <Pane fx:id="top" layoutX="-1.0" prefWidth="879.0" styleClass="appNav">
          <children>
            <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="6.0" spacing="10.0">
              <children>
                <Label prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="32.0" styleClass="titleBarHome" />
                <Label prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="32.0" styleClass="titleBarPublisher" />
                <Label prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="32.0" styleClass="titleBarTools" />
              </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="667.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="197.9998779296875" spacing="5.0">
              <children>
                <TextField prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="searchTextField" />
              </children>
            </HBox>
          </children>
        </Pane>
        <Pane id="leftNav" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="52.0" prefHeight="511.999977929685" prefWidth="652.0" styleClass="centerPane">
          <children>
            <VBox id="VBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="21.0" spacing="5.0">
              <children>
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Accounts" />
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Cases" />
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Callender" />
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Matters" />
              </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="110.0" spacing="5.0" styleClass="leftVBoxProfile">
              <children>
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Profile and settings" />
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Firm staff" />
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Firm Interns" />
                <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Affiliates Firms" />
              </children>
            </VBox>
            <Pane id="contentPane" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="21.0" prefHeight="436.0" prefWidth="525.999977929685" styleClass="centerPaneCct">
              <children>
                <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" spacing="10.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label minHeight="32.0" minWidth="32.0" styleClass="centerMail" />
                  </children>
                </HBox>
                <Label layoutX="253.0" layoutY="8.0" styleClass="centerNotes" text="NOTES" />
                <Pane fx:id="homeContentDisplay" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="404.0" prefWidth="526.0">
                  <children>
                    <VBox id="VBox" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="15.0" prefWidth="498.0" spacing="5.0" styleClass="centerPaneCctHomeNotifierVWrapper">
                      <children>
                        <Label styleClass="centerPaneCctHomeNotifierTtl" text="Notifications" />
                        <Label styleClass="centerPaneCctHomeNotifierNone" text="none listed" />
                      </children>
                    </VBox>
                    <VBox id="VBox" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="62.0" prefWidth="498.0" spacing="5.0" styleClass="centerPaneCctHomeNotifierVWrapper">
                      <children>
                        <Label fx:id="label" styleClass="centerPaneCctHomeNotifierTtl" text="Activities today" visible="false" />
                        <Label styleClass="centerPaneCctHomeNotifierNone" text="none listed" />
                      </children>
                    </VBox>
                    <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="435.0" layoutY="342.0" spacing="5.0" styleClass="centerSocialTabsOnlineHWrapper">
                      <children>
                        <Label prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="24.0" styleClass="centerSocialTabsOnline" />
                        <Label prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="24.0" styleClass="centerSocialTabsBlogs" />
                        <Label prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="24.0" styleClass="centerSocialTabsQA" />
                      </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="109.0" styleClass="centerPaneKIWI" text="KIWI" />
                    <TextField fx:id="KIWITextField" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="134.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="498.0" styleClass="HomeKIWI" />
                    <Label id="labelShows" fx:id="GoKIWI" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="421.0" layoutY="176.0" prefWidth="91.0" styleClass="centerPaneKIWIPost" text="Post KIWI" />
                    <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="202.0" prefWidth="498.0" styleClass="centerPaneKIWIPostStatus" text="No KIWIs posted yet" />
                    <Pane layoutY="315.0" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="435.0" styleClass="footerFilesPane">
                      <children>
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" styleClass="footerFilingNone" text="No files from this firm attached to Wakili yet." />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="36.0" styleClass="footerFilingNew" text="Attach new file here" />
                        <Label layoutX="397.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="24.0" styleClass="footerFilingHelp" />
                      </children>
                    </Pane>
                    <Label layoutX="57.0" layoutY="-32.0" minHeight="32.0" minWidth="32.0" styleClass="centerContacts" />
                  </children>
                </Pane>
                <Pane fx:id="page2ContentDisplay" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="404.0" prefWidth="526.0" visible="false">
                  <children>
                    <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonActionShowHome" text="Page 2" />
                  </children>
                </Pane>
              </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane layoutX="-5.0" layoutY="457.0" prefWidth="656.999977929685">
              <children>
                <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="-6.0" layoutY="12.0" prefWidth="336.0" spacing="20.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" styleClass="footerDocuments" text="Documents" />
                    <Label alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" styleClass="footerMasterTables" text="Master Tables" />
                    <Label alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" styleClass="footerFiling" text="Modules" />
                  </children>
                </HBox>
              </children>
            </Pane>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="222.0" prefWidth="111.0" styleClass="leftPanePersonalArea" text="My personal area" />
            <VBox id="VBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="250.0" spacing="5.0">
              <children>
                <Label styleClass="leftPanePersonalAreaLinks" text="My profile" />
                <Label styleClass="leftPanePersonalAreaLinks" text="Wakili forums" />
                <Label styleClass="leftPanePersonalAreaLinks" text="Shared data" />
              </children>
            </VBox>
          </children>
          <padding>
            <Insets right="10.0" />
          </padding>
        </Pane>
        <VBox id="VBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="710.0" layoutY="63.0" spacing="5.0" styleClass="rightPaneBillTaxVBox">
          <children>
            <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Billing and Tax" />
            <Label styleClass="centerPaneNavLeft" text="Payment management" />
          </children>
        </VBox>
        <Pane layoutX="666.0" layoutY="107.0" prefHeight="404.0" prefWidth="197.99990000000253" styleClass="rightPane">
          <children>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" styleClass="firmTitle" text="Kirundi &amp; co. Advocates" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="32.0" styleClass="rightPaneBackUp" text="Back-up firm data online" />
            <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="94.0" spacing="10.0" styleClass="rightPaneKSLLSKHWrapper">
              <children>
                <Label styleClass="rightPaneKSLLSK" text="LSK" />
                <Label styleClass="rightPaneKSLLSK" text="KSL">
                  <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets />
                  </HBox.margin>
                </Label>
              </children>
            </HBox>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="120.0" styleClass="rightPaneTheCourts" text="The courts" />
            <VBox id="VBox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="143.0" spacing="5.0">
              <children>
                <Label styleClass="rightPaneTheCourtsLinks" text="Announcements" />
                <Label styleClass="rightPaneTheCourtsLinks" text="Popular cases" />
              </children>
            </VBox>
            <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="75.0" styleClass="rightPaneFirmWebsite" text="Go to firm website" />
          </children>
        </Pane>
        <Label layoutX="746.0" layoutY="511.0" styleClass="footerCAMPORey" text="CAMP - ORey" />
      </children>
    </Pane>
  </children>
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
  </padding>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@../Styling/Buttons.css" />
    <URL value="@../Styling/Direction.css" />
    <URL value="@../Styling/Labels.css" />
    <URL value="@../Styling/Panes.css" />
    <URL value="@../Styling/Text.css" />
    <URL value="@../Styling/TextArea.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Sample.FXML** *(after copy-paste from Home.FXML)*

```
*Identical to home above*
```

**Update:**

The error message:

```
Controller method "handleButtonActionShowHome" not found.
file:/D:/xampp/htdocs/Jive/WakiliProject/dist/WakiliProject.jar!/wakiliproject/Home.fxml:94
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:492)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:589)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2430)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2136)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2744)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2709)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2696)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
  at wakiliproject.WakiliProject.start(WakiliProject.java:13)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller method "handleButtonActionShowHome" not found.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:492)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:589)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2430)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2136)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2709)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2696)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at wakiliproject.WakiliProject.start(WakiliProject.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 52 seconds)
```

Comment: Any error is raised ?

Comment: Just added the error. Hope it is useful.

Comment: "WakiliProject.jar could not be deleted." => you are maybe running the file somewhere (check if you have anything running in your Netbeans status bar).

Comment: WakiliProject.jar seems to be in use. Stop it if it is executing. Or open task manager and terminate the appropriate "java" thread (presumably the one that have minimum memory footprint). The last but the solid choice will be restarting the Windows ;).

Comment: I just updated the error message. The program won't run.

Comment: Just fixed the problem. Seems like a JavaFx project can't run without a method called from the FXML file not being declared in the controller! Thanks guys. I forgot to remove the method from the earlier project on copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

A method called from the FXML file must be included somewhere in the controller class.

In this case the `handleButtonActionShowHome()` method had not been included in the `SampleController` class.